# Why does TensorFlow calculate 2D convolutions when 1D convolution is called?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

In the documentation of tf.nn.conv1d, it is stated that

> Internally, this op reshapes the input tensors and invokes tf.nn.conv2d. For example, if data_format does not start with "NC", a tensor of shape [batch, in_width, in_channels] is reshaped to [batch, 1, in_width, in_channels], and the filter is reshaped to [1, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]. The result is then reshaped back to [batch, out_width, out_channels] (where out_width is a function of the stride and padding as in conv2d) and returned to the caller.

I get that the operations are equivalent, but I am a bit confused about the implications of this implementation detail.

Does the reshaping create some computational overhead? 
The 3D convolution has its own implementation, so why not the 1D convolution?

Thanks for any explanation that helps me and others to understand this implementation detail of TensorFlow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through the source code, I conclude that it's likely done for convenience and minimalism of implementation - details below.

First, there is no "reshaping", only expanding, squeezing, and re-ordering dims, which bears a tiny overhead; no array elements are actually being moved in memory - only the tensor object's indexing specifiers are changed.

Second, all `conv` ultimately route to [`tf.nn_ops.convolution_internal`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L942), which then routes to either `gen_nn_ops.conv2d` or `gen_nn_ops.conv3d`; a `conv1d` does not exist in `gen_nn_ops.py`. Note that for some reason, you won't find that file in the Git respository - but it should be in your local install, `/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py`.

Lastly, to get a real answer on why there isn't a dedicated `conv1d` implementation, you'll need to ask the cuDNN developers behind the convolution algorithms found in `gen_nn_ops.py`; it's possible that they found no performance improvements, and that `conv2d` works just as fast. From a low-level standpoint, this makes sense, as the number of matrix multiplications in sliding a kernel with `N x 1` elements along an `M x 1` input is identical to that of `N` along `M` - again, the only difference is in indexing.

Unfortunately devs decided to encapsulate the ultimate call, that is to `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute`; the module consists of a `.lib` and a `.pyd` file - basically, compiled C (Cython) code that requires disassembly for introspection.

---

TL;DR (1) the "reshaping" has a trivial overhead; (2) lack of a dedicated `conv1d` implementation is likely per sparing redundancy as `conv2d` is just as fast; (3) I'm not a cuDNN expert, so if you need to be sure, better ask over at [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn), or read their [SDK Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html). Alternatively, a dev at [TF Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) may help. I haven't seen cuDNN devs answer on SO for years now, so posting here may not be the best bet.

---

**Dim reordering performance demo**:

```py
import numpy as np
from time import time

x = np.random.randn(700, 800, 900) # 504,000,000 elements

t0 = time()
for i in range(1000):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x = x.reshape(700, 900, 800)
    else:
        x = x.reshape(700, 800, 900)
print(time() - t0)
```

```
0.0009968280792236328
```